# Get result of command java -version in c++

Tags: java, c++, redirect, cmd, pipe

I am trying to see whether or not the installed java version is good to run from c++.

I looked everywhere, yet neither [pipes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/478898/how-do-i-execute-a-command-and-get-the-output-of-the-command-within-c-using-po) nor redirecting the system() call using "cmd + > txtfile.txt" seem to work with the output of "java -version".

I have no idea why, maybe the output stream can't be redirected?

All help is very much appreciated!

Comment: What code have you tried? Can you [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/58422474/edit) and show your best attempt?

Comment: Show a [mcve] of your current code. Hint: when you do `java -version`, Java responds on stderr (file descriptor 2), not on stdout (file descriptor 1). (which you can verify on the command line with a `>` redirect for stdout and a `2>` redirect for stderr)

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that "java -version" responds on stderr, which must be redirected using 2> not >.

**In conclusion**

Write output to file using '2> filename.txt'

```
system("java -version &> temp.txt");

std::ifstream fin("temp.txt");

std::string Result = "";
std::string Line;

while(getline(fin, Line))
    Result+=Line;

fin.close();
```

(Thanks to Erwin Bolwidt)

Comment: You coud use of course also the `&>` symbol to get both stdout and stderr.